# FilePaths in C# and VB.NET (via WCF)

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I have a WCF which I can call from a VB.NET application like this:

```
Dim tcp As New TCPService2.Service1Client

ExStreamPath = "C:\Program Files\Exstream\Dialogue 6.1\Engine.exe"
datPath = "-FILEMAP=DataFile,\\Dev-srv1\Exstream\LetterWriterApp\Input Files\Data Files\SAVEezkazivaftf40s452ndayb45.dat"
optPath = "-CONTROLFILE=C:\Exstream\Development\LetterWriter\ControlFiles\Letter.opt"

tcp.StartExStream(datPath, optPath, ExStreamPath)
```

The previous code kicks off a subroutine in a WCF (written in VB.NET), which uses the process object to start a 3rd party executable (with the arguments listed above). The code works great.

But, I'm having problems making the same type of call with C#. I think it might have something to do with a VB WCF being passed C# filepaths (the whole double-\\ thing), but I'm not sure. When trying to run the following code, I'm getting a 'File Not Found' error. The paths have been copied and pasted, so I know the paths are identical. Here's the C#:

```
tcpExstream.Service1Client MyTCP = new tcpExstream.Service1Client();

string ExStreamPath;
string datPath;
string optPath;

ExStreamPath = @"C:\Program Files\Exstream\Dialogue 6.1\Engine.exe";
datPath = @"-FILEMAP=DataFile,\\Dev-srv1\Exstream\LetterWriterApp\Input Files\Data Files\SAVEezkazivaftf40s452ndayb45.dat";
optPath = @"-CONTROLFILE=C:\Exstream\Development\LetterWriter\ControlFiles\Letter.opt";

 MyTCP.StartExStream(ExStreamPath, datPath, optPath);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Comment: I suggest you try to remove the @'s and flip the \ to / maybe it will work... just try

Comment: @OmerPT: The @ signs are correct. The VB and C# code will result in the same *string* representations.

Comment: Yeah but my point was maybe flipping them will work, I had windows giving problems with that stuff in the past... just wanted you to try, also why I posted it as a comment... Anyway someone already answered you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your arguments appear in a different order between the two.

Compare:

```
tcp.StartExStream(datPath, optPath, ExStreamPath)
```

With:

```
MyTCP.StartExStream(ExStreamPath, datPath, optPath);
```